# XPath query with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

What do you think the correct XPath is to pull the dublin core identifier below?

I added a namespace manager with these entries:

```
// Add the namespace.  
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(m_xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("mets", "http://www.loc.gov/METS/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("dcterms", "http://purl.org/dc/terms/");
```

And I have tried 15 or so different XPath iterations including the ones below.  When I do not get an error, the result is null.

```
//xml_uuid = m_xml.SelectSingleNode("/mets:mets/mets:dmdSec/mets:mdWrap/mets:xmlData/dcterms:dublincore/dc:identifier").Value;
xml_uuid = m_xml.SelectSingleNode("//dc:identifier",nsmgr).Value;
```

Here is the xml I am working with:

```
<mets:mets xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/METS/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/version18/mets.xsd">
 <mets:metsHdr CREATEDATE="2017-03-08T20:13:27" />
 <mets:dmdSec ID="dmdSec_1">
   <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="DC">
     <mets:xmlData>
       <dcterms:dublincore xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://purl.org/dc/terms/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcterms.xsd">

         <dc:identifier>F2015.5</dc:identifier>

       </dcterms:dublincore>
     </mets:xmlData>
   </mets:mdWrap>
 </mets:dmdSec>
 etc...
```

I am trying to assign the dc:identifier - F2015.5 in this case - to a string.

Comment: There is no problem with the XPath expression provided you have bound `dc` prefix to the namespace URI `"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"`. See http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e5192bd8b00933c828aea65be940b6de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xml linq and ignoring the namespaces :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication131
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string results = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "identifier").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting the xml from an api so i had to do this:  `XDocument.Parse(m_xml.OuterXml);` but your approach worked without declaring the namespaces. txs.

Comment: Yes.  Use Parse when you have a string and Load when reading file or stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **one** working answer.  I believe the main thing is to use .InnerText and not .Value.

```
xml_uuid = m_xml.SelectSingleNode("//mets:xmlData[1]/dcterms:dublincore[1]/dc:identifier[1]", nsmgr).InnerText;
```